# StackedBar Histogram mouse event

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I have an histogram created with `JFreeChart` API. This is a StackedBar Histogram:

[image]

My histogram represents the datas in the `JTable` on the right. For example the field `thea=11` is present two times as Int32 and two times as Int64. 
I implemented a mouse event on my chart: when one presses on a bar the corresponding record of the Jtable is selected. 
For example if one presses `11.0` bar in the JTable I get:

[image]

This is my listener:

```
chartPanel.addChartMouseListener(new ChartMouseListener() {
    @Override
    public void chartMouseMoved(ChartMouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent arg0) {

        try{
        TableModel model = table.getModel();    
        CategoryItemEntity entity = (CategoryItemEntity) arg0.getEntity();
        Comparable row = entity.getRowKey();
        Comparable col = entity.getColumnKey();
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(row));
        String field = String.valueOf(col);

            for(int i = 0; i<model.getRowCount(); i++) {
                if(model.getValueAt(i, 0).equals(field)) {

                    int realRowNumber = table.convertRowIndexToView(i);
                    table.changeSelection(realRowNumber, 0, false, false);
                    break;

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("No bar selected");
        }
    }
});
```

Listener works with a single bar, but it does not work correctly when I have the bar divided in two or more portions.
For example if I press on the blue portion of `11` bar, the selected row in the `JTable` on the right is the first with `11` as `thea`, so in my case the selected row is `[11,Int32,2]` instead of `[11,Int64,2]` that is the right row to select.

Comment: Don't you have to search for the _whole_ key, rather than just a single `field`?

Comment: Your tip to consider the whole key works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).